# WCF .svc worked but not the config file

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0

I am trying to use the configuration file to define endpoint and services information. I have a very simple code that contain OneWay service and a Duplex service. The OneWay worked when I haven't try to alter the configuration file.

Now, I want to use the configuration file to define both service.

Service1 contract name is `IOneWayService` and the Service2 contract name is `ICallBackService`.

Both have implemented code in their concrete respective classes name `OneWayService.svc.cs` and `CallBackService.svc.cs`.

The configuration file at this moment look like that :

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
   </system.web>
   <system.serviceModel>
      <serviceHostingEnvironment  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
         <serviceActivations>
            <add relativeAddress="OneWayService.svc" service="TestingWcf.OneWayService"/>
            <add relativeAddress="CallBackService.svc" service="TestingWcf.CallBackService"/>
         </serviceActivations>
      </serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <services>
         <service name="TestingWcf.OneWayService">
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:60847/One"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="IOneWayService" />
         </service>
         <service name="TestingWcf.CallBackService">
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:60847/Two"
               binding="wsHttpBinding"
               contract="IDuplexService" />
         </service>
      </services>
      <behaviors>
         <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
               <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
               <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
   </system.serviceModel>
   <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I always have this error when trying to execute the OneWayService via this url : `http://localhost:60847/OneWayService.svc`

> The contract name 'IOneWayService'
>   could not be found in the list of
>   contracts implemented by the service
>   'OneWayService'.

Anybody have an idea why?

### Edit

I have removed the `multipleSiteBindingsEnabled= true` from the `servinceHostingEnvironment` tag and in the contract added the namespace and I could runt the OneWayService.

Also, the Duplex cannot be bound to the `wsHttpBinding`. I had to change it to `NetTcpBinding`. But, I had an other error with the Duplex :

> Configuration binding extension
>   'system.serviceModel/bindings/NetTcpBinding'
>   could not be found. Verify that this
>   binding extension is properly
>   registered in
>   system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions
>   and that it is spelled correctly.

From this point, I am lost again.

### Edit 2

I did an error in the binding name. I had a capital letter for NetTcpBinding and it does require a lowercase: `netTcpBinding`. However, it's still not working, now I have:

> The protocol 'net.tcp' is not
>   supported. >.< !!!

Comment: Are you hosting this in IIS (which version??), or are you self-hosting (in e.g. a Windows NT Service) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, that explains it - Visual Studio by default uses the built-in Cassini web server (unless you've already switched to using [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx)) - and that server doesn't support anything but plain http.

Cassini doesn't support net.tcp and anything like that.

You will need to start using a separate IIS virtual directory and first enable all the necessary support stuff (in the Add/remove Windows Features dialog)